# build not found in iTunes

Tags: ios, iphone, build, app-store-connect, xcode7

I have successfully uploaded build from Xcode 7 but can't find build in build Section in iTunes. Its about 1 hour to uploaded build.

Please tell me what to do. I have uploaded build again but still not able to find build in build Section or Prerelease section.

Comment: See my (updated) answer. it seems to be solved.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening with due to 'Xcode 7'. May be your 'Xcode 7' is infected for more information you can check below link

http://9to5mac.com/2015/09/20/xcode-ghost-app-store-malware-malicious-apps/

Comment: Thanks for reply. But now there is a build in Prerelease section but not in build section

Answer (score 0):

I am having the exact same issue. Try closing your browser, removing all the cookies related to Apple, login and see if it helps (I highly doubt it will, but anyway).

I've uploaded my binary 2 hours ago using Xcode 7 but I still don't see my build in iTC. I guess it's a temporary issue with Apple and all we can do is to wait.

**UPDATE:** It is solved for me after waiting. I've submitted my binary successfully for review.

Comment: I have done what you said but no success. Now I have found that My app icon is in jpg format and contains alpha. So I uploaded app icon in png format without containing alpha. Now I have uploaded bulid again with changing build version. Now lets see what happens.

Comment: I don't think that is an issue. If it was an issue you'd get a validation error in the very beginning. But anyway, just wait, check in an hour or two, it should be resolved.

Comment: :( not finding build in build tab even new uploaded build are not available in prerelease tab.

Comment: Please tell me what to do. Still not found build in versions or prerelease Tab

Comment: If it's still the same, I think you should contact Apple at iTunes Connect support about it.